# ubuntu 11.10 install 4.4.3-0ubuntu2 package dependencies

Tags: dependencies

before `sudo apt-get install gnuplot`
I `sudo apt-get build-dep gnuplot` to resolve package dependencies.

```
~$ sudo apt-get build-dep gnuplot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-0-dev' instead of 'liblua5.1-dev'
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgd2-xpm ubuntu-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  debhelper diffstat html2text intltool-debian libbsd-dev
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libedit-dev libexpat1-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgd2-noxpm libgd2-noxpm-dev
  libglib2.0-dev libjpeg62-dev liblua5.1-0-dev libncurses5-dev libpango1.0-dev
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev libtinfo-dev
  libwxbase2.8-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxft-dev libxrender-dev po-debconf quilt texinfo wx2.8-headers
  x11proto-render-dev
0 upgraded, 34 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,100 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

It says the "ubuntu-desktop" will be removed,
but "ubuntu-desktop" is important.
What's should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that libgd2-noxpm and libgd2-xpm conflict as far as I can tell.

I would try `sudo apt-get install debhelper diffstat html2text intltool-debian libbsd-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libedit-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev  libglib2.0-dev libjpeg62-dev liblua5.1-0-dev libncurses5-dev libpango1.0-dev libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev libtinfo-dev libwxbase2.8-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxft-dev libxrender-dev po-debconf quilt texinfo wx2.8-headers`

Then building against libgd2-xpm instead and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you. I follow your advice, and there is not conflict with libgd2-xpm sofar.

Comment: Thanks,  I meant that was why you were getting an ubuntu-desktop removal request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ubuntu-desktop is extremely important, your system cannot function without it. This is a bug in the required dependencies of gnuplot, please report it on launchpad.net.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for taking the time to make Ubuntu better!